# get integer and string from string, java

Tags: java

I have a String variable that is defined like this:

`String str= "245   Hello world";`.

Is there a way to split this string into integer `a=245` and string `b="Hello world"` ?

The existing white space between the number and the text is not defined. The certain is that I always have an integer followed by a text.

Comment: sure. Use a regular expression.

Comment: What does "is not defined" mean? Can it be "123Hello"?

Comment: you are right. The white space must be one or more. I will edit the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner("245   Hello world");
int i = sc.nextInt();
String s = sc.nextLine().trim();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a RegEx to separate the numbers:

```
String str= "245 Hello world";
Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("/(\d+)/g");
Matcher mat = pat.matcher(str);
String num;
if(mat.find()){
    num = mat.group(1);
}
str.replace(num, "");
```

And parseint to get an integer:

```
int x = Integer.parseint(num);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use split():

```
    Integer a = Integer.parseInt(str.split(" ", 2)[0]);
    String b = str.split(" ", 2)[1].trim();
```

Answer (score -1):

you can do Str.substring(0,3) to get the number and str.substring(4, str.length()-3) to get the rest and trimmed it.
Other solution si to use str.split(" ") which will split the string in 3 parts, the first is the number the rest you concatenate to get the message.